# WPF DateTimeUpDown Binding Problem

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I am using the WPF Toolkit's [DateTimeUpDown](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=DateTimeUpDown&referringTitle=Home) inside a DataGridTemplateColumn (It isnt in the regular release, it is only available in the latest code changes). I have bound it to a DateTime property from one of my classes, where the DataGrid is in turn, bound to an ObservableCollection of said classes. Every column in the DataGrid apart from the one that includes the DateTimeUpDown control. My class implements INotifyPropertyChanged as the ObservableCollection itself does. Also, i override the ObservableCollection's Insert so i hook each of the added objects' NotifyPropertyChanged Delegate so i update the backend database with each change. My problem is... the delegate never gets fired even though i change the date using the control. Any Ideas?

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="LDary.Deudas"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:t="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Controls;assembly=WPFToolkit.Extended"
    Title="Deudas" Height="300" Width="300" Name="WinDeudas" Closing="WinDeudas_Closing">
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <DataGrid Grid.Row="0" Name="Lista" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=WinDeudas, Path=SDeudas}"
              GridLinesVisibility="None" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False"
              CanUserResizeRows="False" IsTextSearchEnabled="True" IsReadOnly="False"
              AlternatingRowBackground="#FFF0F0F0" BorderBrush="#FFF0F0F0"
              ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" RowHeaderWidth="0">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="ID" Binding="{Binding Path=ID}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Nombre" Binding="{Binding Nombre}" Width="*" IsReadOnly="True"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Cedula" Binding="{Binding Cedula}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Telefono" Binding="{Binding Telefono}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Caracteristica" Binding="{Binding Caracteristica}"  IsReadOnly="True"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Fecha" Binding="{Binding Fecha}"  IsReadOnly="True"/>
            <!--<DataGridTextColumn Header="Fecha Limite" Binding="{Binding FechaPago}" />-->
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Fecha Limite" IsReadOnly="False">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <t:DateTimeUpDown Value="{Binding FechaPago}" Format="LongDate"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Valor" Binding="{Binding Valor}" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
    <TextBox Name="txtBusqueda" Grid.Row="1" Padding="0,5"/>
    <Button Name="BtnGuardar" Grid.Row="2" Padding="0,5" Content="Guardar Cambios" Click="BtnGuardar_Click"/>
</Grid>
```

Code:

```
    public new void Insert(int index, Deuda Item)
    {
        Item.PropertyChanged += new PropertyChangedEventHandler(PropertyChangedHandler);
        base.Insert(index, Item);
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? Experiencing something very similar

Comment: @chillitom I got around it somehow back then, dont have the source code for that right now :/ Try the answers below maybe?

Comment: just use OnValueChanged(), nothing else worked for me

Answer (score 2):

Add

`UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged`

to your DateTimeUpDown control binding, like this

```
<t:DateTimeUpDown Value="{Binding FechaPago, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Format="LongDate"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you have to fire the ***PropertyChanged* event** of the underlying INotifyPropertyChanged **DataContext** object by your own:

```
private DateTime _fechaPago;

public DateTime FechaPago
{
    get { return this._fechaPago; }

    set
    {
        this._fechaPago = value;
        this.OnPropertyChanged("FechaPago");
    }
}

protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{
    if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
        this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

The DataContext object must tell that one of its properties changed.

Comment: The setter of the container class for FechaPago already fires the delegate. In fact, it gets fired when the info from the DB is transformed into BL objects. What i mean is, why the DateTimeUpDown's binding is set to OneWay even though i manually setting it to TwoWay :/